# How to start muli process in background with supervisor on Docker

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, supervisord, dockerfile

With my dockerfile I try to run 2 process in background (Tor and Polipo) with supervisor.
My Dockerfile look like that:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Upgrade system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y --no-install-recommends && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean

# Install TOR
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tor tor-geoipdb torsocks && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean

# INSTALL POLIPO
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y polipo
# INSTALL SUPERVISOR
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor


# Default ORPort
EXPOSE 9001

# Default DirPort 
EXPOSE 9030

# Default SOCKS5 proxy port 
EXPOSE 9050

# Default ControlPort
EXPOSE 9051
# Default polipo Port
EXPOSE 8123

RUN echo 'socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"'  >> /etc/polipo/config
RUN echo 'socksProxyType = socks5'  >> /etc/polipo/config
RUN echo 'diskCacheRoot = ""' >> /etc/polipo/config

RUN echo 'ORPort 9001' >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo 'ExitPolicy reject *:*' >> /etc/tor/torrc
ADD supervisor_tor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/tor.conf
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n
```

and my supervisor_tor.conf look like that:

```
[group:tor]
programs=polipo,tor

[program:polipo]
command=/usr/bin/polipo -c /etc/polipo/config
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:tor]
command=/usr/bin/tor
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

Once my countainer is running, I see all the log I don't access on the bash.

How I can start 2 process in background with supervisor ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little lost as I don't understand what "I see all the log I don't access on the bash" means.

However, it sounds like you the problem is you want your bash prompt back. If that's the case, just give the `-d` argument to `docker run` when starting your image. If you want to get another shell, just `docker exec` e.g:

```
$ docker exec -it mycon bash
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. Actually when I launch my countainer with this commande: docker run -i -t id_image, I haven't got the "hand" on  bash, because supervisor display all the informations.

Comment: yeah, so don't do that. Do `ID=docker run -d id_image` then `docker exec -it $ID bash`

Comment: what version of docker you use?

Comment: what does that matter? I'm on Docker 1.7, but exec has been around for a few versions now.

Comment: I just upgrade docker ( because by default with ubuntu is 1.1 ), and the command "docker exec" doesn't work.
thanks very much.

Comment: You should follow the instructions here https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/ to install Docker (you might want to check the script before running it).